# Concatenate a string to each file line

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file (delete_names.txt) with a name by line. The file have around 200 lines, like this:

```
ABAA742_2012-01-13_decont.fa
ABAA1502_2014-08-08_decont.fa
```

I want read each line of the file and concatenate the string ".faa" in the end of each line in order to get:

```
ABAA742_2012-01-13_decont.fa.faa
ABAA1502_2014-08-08_decont.fa.faa
```

I try to get the final string, but the sub string is always added in the start.

```
while read line; do
a='.faa'
echo -E "$line$a"; 
done < delete_names.txt
```

output from the code above:

```
.faa742_2012-01-13_decont.fa
.faa1502_2014-08-08_decont.fa
```

The final goal, after get the concatenated name is to delete the file inside the directory.

Comment: Strange, I just ran your code as is and got the expected result.

Comment: I do not know what happened. I was always obtaining this. Probably, some difference in the system at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Short **`sed`** + **`xargs`** approach:

```
sed 's/$/.faa/' delete_names.txt | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

---

Or just with single **`xargs`** command:

```
xargs -a delete_names.txt -I {} rm {}.faa
```

- `-a file` - read items from `file` instead of standard input

Comment: Thank you very much. It is more simple than the way I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use [gnu-parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for those kind of jobs, it could be something like:

```
cat delete_names.txt | parallel rm -rf "{}a"
```

what it does is to pipe the each name to the `parallel` command, and it forks the to one or multiple process. I just added `"{}a"` but you can also use `"{.}.faa"` that removes the extension of the your string.